# Is This force applied considered as Work or Torque ,And how do you calculate it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, torque

When I look at the life of one of the most successful arm wrestlers like (Alexy Voevoda), their training is awesome, I had seen a video of him pulling against 3rd person in arm wrestling.

[image: Source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJTZAd4l590]

[image: Source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJTZAd4l590]

Source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJTZAd4l590

3rd Person is pulling his arm in arm wrestling, with 2 straps so basically let's assume that the length of each of the straps that the 2 persons are pulling is (1m) how do you calculate the force that the arm wrestling champion (Alexy Voevoda) is exerting to resist their forces.

I have very little understanding about physics so if I'm wrong please correct me.

Also sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Reality doesn't care about how you calculate something. If you have calculated the force to be that amount, then you can't dismiss it by instead thinking about it in terms of torque (which you seem to be miscalculating).

Comment: im go going to edit the question,i will remove my wrong calculations.